# How do you keep taking inputs constantly in C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say that the input is like this:

> 2
>   xsad
>   sadsad

There are no constraints so how do you create a loop that will keep on going that will store each of those in a string?

Like the first number is the amount of lines of strings. How do you create a loop function that would read the first number ex: 1000 and keep storing it in different strings?

Comment: What is a loop function? Do you mean a simple for loop?

Comment: i meant loop, my bad

Comment: create an array of std::string or char* big as the first input, and than do a loop from 0 to that number

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: The first result for "read input loop c++" on google should have your answer - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/221808/

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` and `std::vector` *as necessary* (some online judge exercises don't need to store the data):

```
int quantity = 0;
std::cin >> quantity;
std::vector<std::string> database;
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
  std::string text;
  std::getline(std::cin, text);
  database.push(text);
}
```

A common *rule of thumb* is to use `for` loop when the number of loops (iterations) is known; otherwise use a `while` loop.